# How to use union in C++ correctly?

Tags: c++, bit, unions

I have following union in C++

```
union MsgData {
      struct
      {
        uint32_t msb : 1;
        uint32_t reg_addr : 7;
        uint32_t data : 8;
        uint32_t fill : 3;
        uint32_t crc : 5;
      } bits;
      uint8_t bytes[3];
    };
```

In case I do following (`address` contains `26`, `data` contains `255` - both in decimal):

```
  msg.bits.msb = 1;
  msg.bits.reg_addr = (address & 0x7F);
  msg.bits.data = data;
  msg.bits.fill = 0;
  msg.bits.crc = 0;
```

the byte array `bytes` inside the union `MsgData` contains:

```
msg.bytes[0]: 53
msg.bytes[1]: 255
msg.bytes[2]: 0
```

I have expected `154` value in the `msg.bytes[0]`. Can anybody give me an advice why I have got `53` instead of `154` value in the `msg.bytes[0]`?

Comment: Details of a bitfield, like whether the elements are stored packed or with padding, are implementation-defined. A union is for saving space, by storing first one type, then another type in the same memory. Storing one type, then reading another is not strictly defined. Also, don't use `uint8_t` when you mean `unsigned char`. One is guaranteed to exist, the other is not. ;-)

Comment: note that `sizeof(bits)` is probably 4 so `bytes` probably should be too

Comment: Bitfields and unions are two of those things that seem great until you learn more about them.

Comment: swapping the first 2 members gives the result you expect: https://godbolt.org/z/d68jWz

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you for your interesting observation. Do you have explanation for that behavior?

Comment: Nope, endian issues? It's all undefined behaviour, if you want an exact but pattern in some bytes construct then manually using shifts and masks

Comment: A union is not designed to cast something in and out. Every time you take some assumptions about memory layout, you are on the wrong way! Every compiler / implementation can store data like it want. Even if it works one day, the next compiler update can change the results. You code is non portable and has UB. So please do not use unions to create non allowed cast operations. They are simply not designed for such use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of your program is undefined because you read from an inactive member of the union.

> How to use union in C++ correctly?

In general: By only reading from the active member of the union which is the one that was assigned last. Exceptions do exist. For example, reading from inactive member that has the same type as the active member is also allowed. There are no such exceptions that would apply to your program.

Since you want to pun the type into array of bytes, there is another, well defined way: `reinterpret_cast`:

```
struct
{
    ...
} bits;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<uint8_t, unsigned char>);
uint8_t* bytes = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&bits);
```

Note that this reading through this `bytes` pointer is allowed specifically because `unsigned char` (along with a few other types) is special.

---

Now, assuming that you use a language extension that defines the behaviour of union type punning or use the `reinterpret_cast` shown above:

> Can anybody give me an advice why I have got 53 instead of 154 value in the msg.bytes[0]?

Because of this:

```
reg_addr | msb | bit field
7654321  | 0   | bit index in order of significance
0011010  | 1   | bit value

0b00110101 == 53
```

It is unclear why you had expected otherwise. Relying on order of bit fields is not portable.

Comment: Another type of exceptions comes from compilers (relying of these exceptions makes code non-portable). For example, GCC allows [some forms of type punning through unions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type-punning).

Comment: It's about time C++ stops treating this kind of usage as UB. There is absolutely no reason to continue to do so, other than annoy developers who need interoperability with C APIs.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal Good luck.

Comment: I don't believe an out-of-the-blue proposal written by a complete outsider stands any chance. I would love to work together with committee members to formulate one though.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. The first step described on the page is to subscribe to their forum, float your idea there, and gather feedback.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: Erm... this kind of "casting by union" is UB in C as well. That doesn't stop it from working *usually*, but you're outside the realm of well-defined behavior.

Comment: @DevSolar Not UB in C unless there are trap representations involved (and character types don't have traps).